# Shell script exporting Hadoop library classpath does not working

Tags: eclipse, shell, pyarrow

I am trying to develop Python client which interacts with Hadoop file system 3.3 using pyarrow package. My OS is CentOS 8 and IDE is Eclipse pydev. The sample code is simple.

```
from pyarrow import fs 
hdfs = fs.HadoopFileSystem('localhost', 9000)
```

But the prerequisite command has to be executed for the successful python codes running. The command is

```
# export CLASSPATH=`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs classpath --glob`
```

Whenever I run Eclipse IDE, I have to execute the above `export CLASSPATH` command before Eclipse. To prevent this inconvenience and to automate the IDE configuration, I make the shell script file like below,

```
#! /bin/bash

export CLASSPATH=$(/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs classpath --glob)
echo $CLASSPATH
```

When I execute this script, output messages from shell script are correct. But when I execute the Eclipse on the next line, the above pyarrow Python codes do not work successfully. I have no idea of this failure.

When I execute the `export CLASSPATH` command on the shell itself, the Python codes on Eclipse work correctly. But when I execute shell script, the Eclipse Python codes throws errors.

### Update

I enter the [Run Configurations] menu and choose [Environment] tab. I click [Add] and input the below values onto [New Environment Variable] Dialog.

```
Name : CLASSPATH
Value : $(/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs classpath --glob)
```

But my configuration is not correct, the same errors are still brought again.

I attach the image of my IDE configuration.

[image]

Comment: If you are running your code from eclipse, you should edit the "Run Configuration" and set the CLASSPATH to the relevant value in the 'environment' tab. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_running_program.htm

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I try to edit "Run Configuration" to set the CLASSPATH in environment tab. But my attempt fails again. Kindly check my Update Part and inform me my mistake.

Comment: I'm not an expert in netbean, but I'd assume it expects "Value" to be a string. In your case you pass it a command that generates a string. To fix it, run the command `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs classpath --glob`, and put the value it returns as the value of CLASSPATH.

Comment: I confirm it works! Thanks and merry christmas ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, in eclipe's "Run Configurations" menu, you need to add en environment variable entry for called `CLASSPATH`.

The value must be whatever the shell returns when you run this command:

```
 /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs classpath --glob
```

Don't try to put `$(/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs classpath --glob)`, it will be interpreted as a string an won't work.